# Regex all expression but not when in other expression

Tags: php, regex

I need to select all

```
<a href="..."><img ...></a>
```

but not when the expression is inside

`[caption]<a href="..."><img ...></a>...[/caption]`

Whith this expression I can select all [caption]

```
/(\[caption[^>]*\](.*?)\[\/caption\])/i
```

So, with this expression I can select all of the a img:

```
/<a[^>]*?href=".*?(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.gif)"[^<]*><img[^>]*><\/a>/i
```

I need to have a combination of the two regex expressions, to select all a>img except it is inside a [caption]. I can negate the first expression with ^, but how can I then select the second?

The regex is used innside PHP with function preg_replace.

Comment: You could try an [prefix `(?<!)` assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), or an alternative with `\K` kill switch to skip `caption…` blocks.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but someting I do wrong. I combine the two regex to:  
`(?<!\[caption[^>]*\](.*?)\[\/caption\])<a[^>]*?href=".*?(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.gif)"[^<]*><img[^>]*><\/a>`
but RegExr  say "Error: The negative lookbeing feautre ist not suppoert in this flavor of RegEX"

Comment: On [https://regexr.com](https://regexr.com/) this was working (it selects the things I like to):
`/(?<!\[caption[^>]*\])<a[^>]*?href=".*?(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.gif)"[^<]*><img[^>]*>/gi`
But the error 'The "negative lookbehind" feature is not supported in this flavor of RegEx.' still exists...

Comment: Yep, no variable-width lookbehinds in PCRE. You will have to use the `/ CAP... \K | <a href= /` approach then.

Comment: This works not for my problem. See 'h\Kd' matches only the second d in adhd. So that's not what I look like. When 'h' is available, then do not take 'd'. So changed for my example:

`(\[caption[^>]*\])\K|<a[^>]*?href=".*?(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.gif)"[^<]*><img[^>]*>`

This takes also a>img inside [caption]. But it should not. Just a>img where are NOT inside [caption]

Comment: In order for this trick to work, you'll need it to consume the innards and end marker as well: `(\[cap].*?\[/cap])\K|…`